# Material for knowing more about Cylinder Chess

Tags: chess-variants

I love the usual way of playing chess, but I also like a lot [Cylinder chess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_chess). Does anybody know a book, website or other way of learning more about it? Like maybe a strategy book about cylinder chess or a book about opening theory on it.

Answer (score 1):

There exists several books presenting quickly various variant of chess, here is one example :
http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/fairy-chess-books-llc/1103593111?ean=9781157372424

About learning strategy or opening theory, both of this concept require a lot of experience and games to be played. For instance in classical chess we had to wait centuries before such thing become available. A first step is to watch games played by the best players. A world championship and tournaments are organized by The Circular Chess Society :
http://www.circularchess.co.uk/

Also, it should be decent training to practice with exercises, many studies has been created with this variant of chess, here is one example :
http://www.mayhematics.com/v/cylin.htm